# Reading until specific line of CSV in Python

Tags: python, csv

I am opening a big CSV file and during inserting the data into the array I got MemoryError. So how can i read specific lines of that CSV file (for example from line 1 till 10000)

here is the code:

```
datafile=open('test.csv','r')
datareader=csv.reader(datafile,delimiter=';')

for row in datareader:
    MyArray.append(row)
```

Comment: How big is your csv file?

Comment: Why are you putting the lines into an array (`list`? `np.array`?), rather than just iterating over them? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The answer by Tim works well, it is more that 1GB, around 9 millions of line. I need the content of data in line (it is network packet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) instead of `enumerate`:

```
from itertools import islice

# First 10000
MyArray.extend(islice(datareader, 10000))

# Or, specify start/stop ranges (10000-20000 (non inclusive))
MyArray.extend(islice(datareader, 10000, 20000))

# Or read in chunks of 10k
for chunk in iter(lambda: list(islice(datareader, 10000)), []):
    # do something with 10k rows
```

Comment: Oh, much nicer. I've never had use for `islice` before, but this is certainly a perfect case. @user3636424, you might want to accept this answer instead.

Comment: @Tim I'm not fussed about accept/reps - just happy it's useful for someone :)

Comment: @JonClements: Me neither, but this is the better answer and should be on top.

Comment: @Tim well - it appears the OP took your advice... thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for i, row in enumerate(datareader):
    MyArray.append(row)
    if i == 10000:
        break
```

or, for any range:

```
start = 1000
stop = 2000
for i, row in enumerate(datareader):
    if i < start: 
        continue     # skip this row
    elif i > stop:
        break        # abort the loop
    else:            # ("else" is not strictly necessary here, but more explicit)
        MyArray.append(row)
```